# openCV java compareHist() value larger than 1

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing, histogram

I am learning openCV and when I tried to compare 2 histograms and print the result the values coming were actually larger than 1. Sorry if it is a stupid question but I am still learning.

Output showing those values:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btbQ3.png)

as you can see in the image the values are in thousands .

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

The third argument of the `compareHist` method selects the comparison function. In your case, the Chi-Square function is used to compare the two histograms, which does not have an upper limit. You could use the correlation comparison function (CV_COMP_CORREL, 0), which is bound between -1 and 1.  See also [this question](http://answers.opencv.org/question/8154/question-about-histogram-comparison-return-value/) on the OpenCV stack exchange.